# Machine learning interview of incorrect claissification

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Here is a problem of machine learning interview:

> For a classification problem, suppose you have labels `a, b, c`. During test samples, suppose the lose that the samples with label `a` are classified as label `c` is very large even compared with being classified as `b` incorrectly. Namely you don't want label `a` sample to be classified as label `c`. How do you improve your algorithm to avoid the large loss in testing?

My idea is give more weight to the samples with label `c` during training. But this would prefer every sample not to be classified as `c` rather than only for the sample with true label `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options come to mind.

1. Apply a weighted loss function that severely penalizes the model for assigning probability to category `c` when the true category is `a`. You might not be getting accurate probability values out of your model, but if it keeps you from making a catastrophic mistake, that might be acceptable.
2. Make accurate probability estimates, and if the probability of category $a$ is too high (where "too high" is determined by how catastrophic it is to mistake an `a` for a `c`), then you go with category `a`, even if `a` is not the category with the majority of the probability density. For instance, your rule might be to assign to category `a` if the probability of category `a` ever exceeds $0.3$, because then the probability of mistaking an `a` for something else is just too high for the damage caused by a misclassification.